# Alguen me podria ayudar a mejorar este algoritmo

Tags: python-3.x

el ejercicio es el siguiente :

Vamos a adquirir una vivienda y para eso necesitaremos una hipoteca. La cuota mensual m que hemos de pagar
para amortizar una hipoteca de h euros a lo largo de n años a un interés compuesto del i por cien anual se calcula con la
formula:

```
m = hr
1 − (1 + r)−12n ,
donde r = i/(100 · 12).
```

Define una función que calcule la cuota (redondeada a dos decimales) dados h, n e i. Utiliza cuantas
variables locales consideres oportuno, pero al menos r debe aparecer en la expresión cuyo valor se devuelve y antes debe
calcularse y almacenarse en una variable local.
Nota: puedes comprobar la validez de tu función sabiendo que hay que pagar la cantidad de 1 166.75 ¤ al mes para
amortizar una hipoteca de 150 000 ¤ en 15 años a un interés del 4.75% anual.

Mi ejercicio quedo así:

```
def calcular(h,n,i):
    r=i/(100*12)
    m=((h*r)/(1-(1+r)**(-12*n)))
    return m
    calcular(150000,15,4.75)

print(calcular(150000,15,4.75))
```

**¿Como podría mejorarlo?** , que pudiera definir las variables o alguna otra mejora.

Answer (score 1):

La fórmula del cálculo de la cuota que pones al principio no se lee bien, pues entiendo que estaba en formato matemático y al pegarlo se ha perdido el formato. Creo que debería ser así:

[image: Formula]

No hay mucho margen de mejora en el código ya que consiste directamente en traducir esa fórmula a la sintaxis Python, cosa que has hecho correctamente.

Las únicas mejoras que se me ocurren son de legibilidad. Es decir, que quien lea el código pueda comprender fácilmente qué se está haciendo. Esto suele hacerse mediante comentarios, documentación y mediante una elección adecuada del nombre de las variables. También el uso de espacios alrededor de los operadores ayuda a leerlos mejor.

Usando estas ideas, la función quedaría así:

```
def calcular_mensualidad(hipoteca, duracion, interes):
    """Esta función calcula el importe de una mensualidad
    de una hipoteca, a partir de los datos de entrada:

      hipoteca: cantidad total prestada
      duracion: duración en años del préstamo 
      interes: interés anual en tanto por ciento
    """

    # Calculo del interés mensual, en tanto por 1
    r = interes/(100*12)

    # Cálculo de la mensualidad, según la fórmula
    mensualidad = (hipoteca * r) / (1 - (1 + r)**(-12 * duracion))
    return mensualidad
```

Observa el uso del *docstring* que es la cadena entre triple comillas que aparece justo debajo de la cabecera de la función. Esta cadena no es un mero comentario, sino que pasa a formar parte de la documentación de la función, y sería mostrada en un intérprete en el que pusieras `help(calcula_mensualidad)`.

Por lo demás, la funcionalidad es exactamente la misma (he quitado la última línea en la que llamabas a `calcular()` pues supongo que se te coló por error; esa línea nunca llegaría a ejecutarse por estar después del `return`, pero si se ejecutara sería peor, pues se llamaba a sí misma y causaría una recursión infinita).